# How to delete entity after all the dependent components has been removed?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2016

I have removed all the components from my entity but when I try to delete it still throw an error. I have tried everything I found on the internet but no luck. Is there anyone who has faced the same issue and able to resolve it?[image: screen shot of error]

Comment: Well - what did you see when you clicked on the "Details" link?? Or the "Show Technical Details" Link?

Comment: @marc_s I see 4 dependent components which were lookup fields I remove them from forms, they are removed from the dependent component of each field but still, it shows on dependent component dectected.

Comment: And after you've removed those fields from the form(s) - did you publish those changes?

Comment: yes, I did. I even publish all in the default solution.

Comment: Click on the entity and then click Show Dependencies in the upper toolbar. This list of dependencies is little different from the Details one.

Comment: You may have to delete the relationships for those lookup fields.

Comment: @MohammadKhubaibNasir can you show the screenshot of pop-up after clicking Details hyperlink? Definitely some subgrid, left navigation link, relationship fields mapping are some items I removed to get rid of dependencies. I can tell you more by seeing screenshot